# Convergence of Improper Integrals to find the value of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\exp(x^2)}\,dx$$

I tried using the Limit comparison for this one:

$$f(x)\leq g(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

Now I can take the integral of $g(x)$. But my problem are the limits $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. How am I supposed to solve this in order to show the convergence? If possible I want to calculate the real value for my integral, i.e. what it converges to.

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt[4]{e}}$$

Comment: You may want to convert $\cos(x)$ into exponential form to just have exponentials in your integral, clean up the terms and you should get exponentials with quadratic powers. Try competing the square and use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is absolutely convergent by your bound, and:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\,e^{-x}\,dx.\tag{1}$$
By expanding
$$ \frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n)!}\tag{2}$$
and integrating termwise through:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-x}\,dx = \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{3}$$
we get, through the [Legendre duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html):
$$ \color{red}{I} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n\, \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n }{4^n\,n!}=\color{red}{\sqrt{\pi}\,e^{-1/4}}\tag{5}$$
and along the same lines we may also prove:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}} e^{-\frac{1}{4s}}.\tag{6}$$

Comment: is there any way i can show this by comparing like how i started in the problem above? Because i can understand none of what you did there. My objective is to understand how to solve it with the limited knowledge of calculus i have been taught for the moment.

Comment: @SherlockHomies: with a limited knowledge of calculus, I am afraid you have no way of computing that integral.

Comment: ok if you say so.

Comment: btw can you help me integrate $$1/e^(x^2)$$?

Comment: @SherlockHomies: I suggest you to use the search function. Such question has already been asked and answered many times on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $x=t^2$ and use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) in conjunction with your knowledge of [Gaussian integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), in order to arrive at the desired result, which has already been posted in the comment section. This will involve completing the square in the exponent, and then making a second simple substitution.

Comment: could you please show me what i should do after my step above? Or is it a dead end?

Comment: Completing the square, in this case, involves a translation by a complex number, and I do not know if the OP is confident with complex analysis. This is the reason for which I provided a real-analytic proof.